# Sorting arraylist of unknown type and throwing an exception if objects are incomparable

Tags: java, exception, generics

Here's my test class with sort method :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person person1 = new Person("Jonas", 36);
        Person person2 = new Person("Petras", 16);

        people.add(person1);
        people.add(person2);

        ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ints.add(6);
        ints.add(5);

        ints = Main.sortAscending(ints);

        System.out.println(ints);
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ArrayList<T> sortAscending(
            final ArrayList<T> list) {
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }
}
```

It works fine as long as I pass in list of primitive types : string, ints, etc. However when I try to pass in list of my objects it doesn't work.

Here's my class :

```
public class Person {
    final String name;
    final int age;

    public Person(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{name=%s, age=%d}", name, age);
    }
}

class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Person person1, final Person person2) {
        return person1.age < person2.age ? -1 : person1.age == person2.age ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

1. How can make my method sortAscending work with my class ?
2. How do I throw an exception of objects I pass in do not have implemented compare method ?

Comment: You need to pass the comparator.

Comment: Unrelated but you should really pass `List` and not `ArrayList` to the method. Never code to an implementation, always code to an interface.

Comment: what's the point of the return value of `sortAscending`, if it always returns what is passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Main.sortAscending` you need to implement the Comparable interface on your Person class and implement the compareTo method

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Person arg0) {
       //your code here to compare object
   }
}
```

Another option is to use the `sort()` method and pass your `Comparator` in.

Comment: `Comparable` is a generic type. Using raw types is a bad idea.

Comment: Changed to Comparable<Person>.  You have a couple options on what class to put in the parameter, so I originally left that as an exercise for the reader,  however I agree it is better to show how that is done.

Answer (score 2):

Send instance of your comparator to `sort()`:

`Collections.sort(list, new AgeComparator());`